# Spring IntegrationFlow with RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I would like to create an application that would perform the following steps:

1. Receive request thru RestController
2. Send the received message to a queue (AMQP - MessageChannel) (correlationId?)
3. Wait for the reply in another queue (AMQP - MessageChannel) (correlationId?)
4. Return the response on the same thread as the request in step 1.

I thought about using IntegrationFlow for this, but I'm not able to adapt the steps.

Besides, would you know what is the best way to implement this flow?

I tried to implement with the following code:

```
package poc.integration.http;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.PollableAmqpChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.dsl.Amqp;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.http.dsl.Http;
import org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationFlowConfig {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationFlowConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway inbound() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
        gateway.setRequestMapping(mapping());
        gateway.setRequestPayloadTypeClass(String.class);
        gateway.setRequestChannelName("httpRequest");
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMapping mapping() {
        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/foo");
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET);
        return requestMapping;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "httpResponse")
    @Bean
    public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler outbound() {
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler =
            new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://10.141.201.206:80/foo");
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
        return handler;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="httpRequest", outputChannel="httpResponse")
    public Object processarMensagem(Object mensagem) {
        return mensagem + " - done";
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata pollerAmqp(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        final PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
        poller.setTaskExecutor(taskScheduler);
        poller.setReceiveTimeout(-1);
        return poller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel httpRequest(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        PollableAmqpChannel channel = new PollableAmqpChannel("httpRequest", amqpTemplate,
                DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper(), DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper());
        channel.setExtractPayload(true);
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel httpResponse(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        PollableAmqpChannel channel = new PollableAmqpChannel("httpResponse", amqpTemplate,
                DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper(), DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper());
        channel.setExtractPayload(true);
        return channel;
    }

}
```

but i'm receiving the message:
No reply received within timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an `IntegrationFlow` with an `Http.inboundControllerAdapter()` as a starting point. It fully replaces the mentioned RestController, but let you to avoid extra work bridging from the `@RestController` to the `IntegrationFlow` and back.

The next step in the flow should be an `Amqp.outboundGateway()` to send and receive over AMQP. This one takes care about a correlation for you.

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-java-config

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#configuring-with-the-java-dsl-4

Comment: With the code I implemented, I receive: No reply received within timeout. What is missing?